# Find if Record already exists in HIVE Table before inserting into it

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE Partitioned Table and before inserting records into it I need to find if the records already exists.

Example.

```
Insert into table employee partition (day, location) select distinct name, number,
date,aud_date, day, location from tableB.
```

If the records I am trying to Insert from tableB already exists in employee table it should bypass or write it into another table. The columns that i need to check if already exists in employee table are name, number, date, day, location. I don't want to check aud_date since it will be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the "number" column is a "not null" column (choose another one to check for null if that were not the case:

(Note: added the "where date >= " inline view from subsequent request of OP)

```
from (
select distinct e.number as e_number, B.name, B.number, b.date, B.aud_date, 
  B.day, B.location 
from tableB B left outer join
   (select * from employee where date >= <blah>) e
   on e.name=B.name and e.number = e.number 
   and  e.date = B.date and e.day=B.day and e.location=B.location
  where e.number is null
) j 
insert overwrite into table employee e 
select j.name, j.number, j.date, j.aud_date, j.day, j.location
```

To answer the question "why is the e.number is null condition there":  Left outer joins ensure that all values from the first table are included in the results. So then what happens when there are no values in the second table: in that case all of the columns from the second table are reported as null.

So in the case above we are searching precisely for the condition that the second table entries are missing - and thus we:

- choose one of the never-empty (aka not null) columns from table two.  So: is number an always-present column? If not then please choose another one
- Specify the condition "table1-alias"."table1-never-null-column" = null.  That means that the record is actually not present in the join condition - and thus we found the records existing only in table 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help..Can you please let me know why are you check if e.number is NULL ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation..One more thing, if i have the table employee partitioned by date, I don't want to scan the entire partition during the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Instead, I want to scan only that particular partition (of employee table)based on the date from tableB. Is it possible ???..We have a large table with 'n' number of partitions..if I scan thru all it will take a lot of time and impacts performance..

Comment: You would need to replace "left outer join employee e" with something like "left outer join (select * from employee where date >= <blah>) e". BTW you can also upvote my answer (in addition to accept). I also updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much..Between I need atleast 15 reputation to 'upvote' while I have only 7 as of now..I am new to this stackoverflow..In the date part, I would need the date from tableB instead of hardcoding it..

Comment: I used a LEFT SEMI JOIN on the date and it worked fine..Thank you so much for your help on this..

Comment: Hi..The LEFT SEMI JOIN works well but it scans thru all the partitions which is impacting the performance/time. I am aware that HIVE doesnot support where IN (SUBQUERY) type..Is there a way to reference left outer join (select * from employee where date IN (select date from table B) so it scans thru only that date partition.